# Python - templated class

Tags: python, django, templates, python-2.7, django-templates

So, I want to create a class which has an associated template. When I run the class' render() method, the template gets processed and returned as a string.

This is what I have so far:

```
class MyClass():
    ...
    def render(self):
        with open(self._template, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK) as template_file:
            html = template_file.read()
        tpl = Template(html)
        return tpl.render(self._template_variables)
```

But this throws an error:

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, if someone has a better suggestion for implementing this, I'm open for ideas.

Comment: It's a property containing '/full/path/to/project/templates/the_template.html'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to duplicate functionality provided in django; but if you must, use [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut):

```
import os
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

class FooClass(object):
    def render(self):
       return render_to_string(os.path.basename(self._template),
                               self._template_variables)
```

I am using [`basename`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) because the `render_to_string` method takes the template name and you are passing it a path.

In general, avoid hard coding thing like file system paths because it makes your code less portable.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I sad if anyone had a better idea, I'm open to it as I'm quite new to Python and Django. This render_to_string function helped me, now everything works ok.

As for the full path, it's not hardcoded, it's computed to a full path, like this:

    `PROJECT_PATH = path.realpath(path.dirname(__file__))
    TEMPLATES_PATH = PROJECT_PATH + '/templates'`

And then in my class' constructor I pass the template path like this:

    `MyClass(TEMPLATES_PATH + '/the_template.html')`

Comment: Make sure you pass `the_template.html` and not `/the_template.html`.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
template_file.close()
```

should not be called within a `with` statement, because its purpose is to release the resources automatically. The `AttributeError` is being throws because you are, essentially, closing the file twice.

Comment: Removing close() doesn't resolve the problem. I still have the same error. And it says it's thrown on the line starting with "with". :/

Comment: I don't think further debugging your code is possible unless you provide more data. Anyway, I'd just follow Burhan Khalid suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

*with* operator makes *close()* method redundant